# React does not include 'disabled' property for HTMLButtonElement type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a component defined as follows:

`function ConfirmableButton(props: { onConfirm: () => void; } & HTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>)`

But when using it like
`<ConfirmableButton disabled={disabledRows.includes(id)} />`, it gives me error `Property 'disabled' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { onConfirm: () => void; } & HTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>'`

What should I be using to make sure the typing is correct?

Comment: Is it possible to share your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The generic type on `HTMLAttributes<T>` is only really there to give the specific element type to its event handlers. Checking the types, `T` in `HTMLAttributes` is only referenced where it extends `DOMAttributes<T>`, which is passed to each event handler to type the target property of the event object.

To get `<button>`-specific attributes, you would need to use React's `ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>` (which is the type React would use for a button element):

```js
interface ButtonHTMLAttributes<T> extends HTMLAttributes<T> {
    autoFocus?: boolean | undefined;
    disabled?: boolean | undefined;
    form?: string | undefined;
    formAction?: string | undefined;
    formEncType?: string | undefined;
    formMethod?: string | undefined;
    formNoValidate?: boolean | undefined;
    formTarget?: string | undefined;
    name?: string | undefined;
    type?: 'submit' | 'reset' | 'button' | undefined;
    value?: string | ReadonlyArray<string> | number | undefined;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the `props` for `ConfirmableButton` as follows:

```
props: { onConfirm: () => void } & ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>
```

This will let you use the component like this:

```js
<ConfirmableButton
  disabled={false}
  onConfirm={() => {
    console.log('Confirmed');
  }}
/>
```